# How can i prevent a drinking glass from getting knocked over?

Tags: cleaning, home, technology, drinks, pets

In *really* rare case when i use a drinking glass on my desk (often I just use bottles) I accidently push it with my elbow, or my cat does it and I need to clean my desk or keyboard.

That happens really rarely, but I'm looking for a hack to prevent it, because it isn't alot fun to clean my mechanical keyboard.

Comment: When I got kids one thing I learned was, in cafes or restaurants, always move all glasses and cups to where the little rascals can't get hold of them. On my desk I deliberately put my cup or glass where I can't knock it over (just to the left of the monitor). Else I have the same problem as you.

Answer (score 3):

First time I ever saw this I thought they were joking. I now have one [no affiliation, I just like it]

[**The Mighty Mug**](http://themightymug.com)

Cannot be knocked over; picks up with no effort.

Caveat - it does require a *reasonably* smooth surface; struggles a bit if there's too much unevenness.

Comment: cool. I'll take it into consideration.

Comment: Avoid this - to see why, check the comments on the kickstarter page - https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jayme39/mighty-mug-the-mug-that-wont-fall/comments

Answer (score 2):

I think you should keep habit of keeping a Water Glass Stand with you to keep your filled drink glass.

This will not resolve your problem but it will definitely decrease the probability of glass knocking over by 99% hence it will reduce your mechanical cleaning work by 99%.

Thanks

Comment: I'm iffy about the percentage *calculations* but other than that I'd say this is the best idea.

Comment: Percentage always vary for person to person. In my case i never get into this problem so i wrote it as this percentage.

Comment: What exactly is a Water Glass Stand? Googling was rather non-conclusive.

Comment: basically a secondary stand/desk for your water glass @Stephie

Comment: @JustDoIt pictures, please...?

Comment: @Stephie its just a table or a [small night stand](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/f3/48/c6/f348c6b077984aa3b6134d0b517f5be0.jpg) whichever works for you

Answer (score 2):

The first think I would think of if I want a glass that does not spill when knocked over is one of the Thermoses used for drinks like Coffee. They have lids that require pressing a button or using some other mechanism to open, so most can not let liquid out without human intervention or not being closed after drinking. Even for some of them the hole is small which limits the amount that can spill when knocked over. They are designed like this to keep the heat in, keeping Coffee hot longer. You can use that to your advantage as well by putting ice in there and it is sure to stay cold for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to the Mighty Mug as it's designed to solve this specific problem.
Also consider getting a sippy cup lid or a SipSnap (see NPR's "[Turn Any Cup Into A Spillproof Sippy Cup](http://www.npr.org/sections/alltechconsidered/2014/06/18/322928681/turn-any-cup-into-a-spill-proof-sippy-cup-for-your-kids)") which are designed to not spill when knocked over (in most design cases, by kids, but these can also solve the problem for cats and stray elbows).

Finally, keep in mind that mugs that are shorter and wider (especially at the base) will have a lower center of gravity and be harder to knock over than something taller and skinnier.  In an extreme case, you could glue/fasten the bottom of your drinking cup on to a flat platform (piece of lead or something wide/heavy), to provide a stable base and give your arm a bit more of a workout each time you go to lift it up for a drink.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use a traditional pint glass (the curved ones that English pubs have plenty of) and would fill it with water. It was a good method of monitoring how much water I drink, but it also had a weighted glass base for this very reason - those darn drunk people knocking over glasses.

I found one in my room the morning after a night at a pub whilst at university, but Ebay have plenty of them. They look great, and are designed to handle light knocks without falling over.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called '[Spink](https://dreamfarm.com/us/spink/)' by Dreamfarm. Silly name notwithstanding, it seems do exactly what you need: provide a little guard for a cup or mug and suctions onto a table to prevent being knocked over.
I own one and it works as advertised. My only complaint with it is how the suction needs to be reapplied to the table every other day, but that takes about two seconds to do.
[image: Red spink]

Disclaimer: I have no stake in the company, nor do I know anybody who works there. I was given this as a gift from a friend who knows I like to have my drink around delicate electronics.

Answer (score -1):

Use an object or a surface which has same height as width of your hand. So whenever by mistake your elbow or hand hits it will push the surface towards the edge of the desk and the glass will fall towards the inside or away from the edge.
Simple physics and conservation of momentum.

Comment: That us *exactly* what OP wants to avoid: flooding the desk and keyboard. Your suggestion seems to *encourage* this outcome.